# Example for topological dual spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.10279) paper and I have a question regarding the following statement (p.8):

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ compact, then $C^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^k)^*,C(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{k\times d})^*$ are the topological dual spaces of $C^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^k)$ and $ C(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{k\times d})$.

Further $M(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^k)$ is the set of $k$-valued signed Borel-measures on $\Omega$.
By Riesz-Markov-Theorem we know that $M(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{k\times d}) = C(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{k\times d})^*$.

Then the characterization $C^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{k})^*$ is done as follows:
For any $g  \in M(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^k)$, we define the linear operator on $C^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{k})$ as

$$\phi \mapsto \int_{\Omega} \langle \phi(x), g(dx)\rangle.$$

The author concludes that $M(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{k,d}) \subseteq C^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{k})^*$.

But in my opinion, it only shows that
$M(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{k}) \subseteq C^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{k})^*$, since  $g \in M(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^k)$. Maybe it works, if we take the operator
$$
\phi \mapsto \int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^d \langle \phi(x), g_i(dx)\rangle.
$$
Why does that work? Thanks!

Comment: I think probably they always want $k\times d$ in the exponent, and then your first argument is the answer, applied to $k=k\times d$.